# Proving that the composition of relations preserves countability

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Suppose there exists a relation $R$ such that $R$ is countable. I would like to prove that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}_1$, $R^{k}$ is countable (assuming that this actually is a true statement, which I intuitively think so, but am not sure about).

I tried to prove this by induction,

- for the base case (for $k=1$) this is true by assumption,
- for the inductive step, I tried to find an injective function from $R^{k+1}$ to $R^k$ (as then by the inductive hypothesis there would exist an injective function from $R^{k+1}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ which would mean that $p^{k+1}$ is countable. However, here  I got a little stuck. Recalling the definition of relation composition,
  $$
  R^{k+1} = \{(a, c) : \text{there exists some $b$ s.t. } (a, b) \in R^k \text{ and } (b, c) \in R\}
  $$
  but from here I was not really sure how to go. I can't show that $R^{k+1} \subseteq R^k$ (as this is true iff $R$ is transitive), but I'm having difficulty finding a way to define a function from $R^{k+1}$ to $R^{k}$ which is injective.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: an injection into $R^k$ will be hard, but maybe you can find an injection of $R^{k+1}$ into $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ (do you know why that is a countable set?)

Comment: Thanks! I think I can do this by first finding a function from $R^{k + 1} \to R^{k} \times R$ (decomposing $(a, c)$ into $(a, b) \in R^{k}$ and $(b, c) \in R$ and then by the inductive hypothesis there is a function from this to $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ which is countable because the cartesian product of countably many sets is countable)?

Comment: Yep, that's correct! (Note that this "decomposition" in general will not be unique, but that's fine, you're just building an injection.) Edit: it's not true in general that the cartesian product of countably many sets is countable, but the cartesian product of _finitely many countable sets_ is countable. In particular, you have two countable sets.